# Angular 14+ production deployment: keep old files or not?

Tags: angular

When we deploy compiled angular app, should we keep old files or delete them? I am using service worker which should cache the files in user's device, but I'm not sure if we should keep the old (hashed) files or not.

My current deployment code removes the old files, but I'm not 100% sure if this is the correct approach since in some cases when a returning user comes back to our app, the browser does not serve cached files but it tries to pull them from the server and those no longer exist.

So what's the best approach here?

And if the answer will be to keep the old files, how shall we then distinguish older versions of the files and remove those? Otherwise the dist folder will be cluttered with many old and no longer needed files.